# wxPython add seperation mark to sizer

Tags: python, wxpython

I have two groups of Check Boxes in `wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)`.
I would like to add something to distinguish that it's two different groups (something else than blank space).
I'm looking for something similar to `AppendSeparator()` of `wx.Menu()`

I've looked in [Sizer Class](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html) but I don't see anything useful there.

I'm trying to avoid adding a StaticText like `|` between the groups, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wx.StaticLine might serve you well